# Logic for if statement that executes code based on exception in Python

Tags: python

I would like to run a script every five minutes in windows task scheduler.  The script reads a JSON web-service of service requests and writes specified fields to an esri geodatabase.

For this process, there is a time stamp, with the information to query the time per service request.

My question is how do I create the logic in this script to say **"Hey, I ran successfully for 12:00PM-12:05:59PM, something happened for 12:06-12:11:59, but I will run for 12:11-12:16:59, and since I am so nice I will grab data for 12:06-12:11."**

the logic that I have built into my code so far is;

```
import datetime


DateofDataCreation = 2015-02-17 16:53:25
i = 5
Start = datetime.datetime.now()
now_minus_5 = Start - datetime.timedelta(minutes =i)


if DateofDataCreation >= now_minus_5:
    WriteToDatabase
else:
    print "No Current Data"
```

Comment: This seems to have been cross-posted to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141439/how-to-raise-exception-from-if-statement-in-python

Answer (score 1):

am not sure if I understand your question exactly. Based on what I think you are asking, try this:

```
import datetime

#If you change the time to be after now() then it will print "WriteToDatabase" .
#If the time is before then it will print "No Current "Data"
DateofDataCreation = datetime.datetime(2015,2,17,16,53,25)

i = 5

Start = datetime.datetime.now()
now_minus_5 = Start - datetime.timedelta(minutes =i)



if DateofDataCreation >= now_minus_5:

     print("WriteToDatabase")
else:
     print ("No Current Data")
```